# CosmosDb 3.2 - aggregate failed without aggregate request

Tags: .net, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a .netcore 3.1 app who interract with CosmosDb 3.2 databases using the mongodb driver.
Given for example this simple request :

```
public void Insert(Core.Entity.Project project)
{
    var _project = _mapperCoreToInfrastructure.MapProject(project);

    _retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
    {
        _mongoCollection.InsertOne(_project);
    });
}
```

Running this piece of code display the following issue :

> Command aggregate failed: The aggregation pipeline is not enabled for
>   this account. Please see https://aka.ms/mongodb-aggregation for
>   details..

I dont have any aggregation request in my repository and I dont want to activage the aggregation feature on azure.

Here is my `MongoClient`configuration in my IOC containers :

```
var url = new MongoUrl(Configuration.GetValue<string>("MongoConnection"));
var mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(url);
mongoClientSettings.RetryWrites = false;
mongoClientSettings.ClusterConfigurator = clusterConfigurator =>
{
    clusterConfigurator.Subscribe<CommandSucceededEvent>(e =>
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackDependency("MongoDb", e.CommandName, e.Reply.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Subtract(e.Duration), e.Duration, true);
    });
    clusterConfigurator.Subscribe<CommandFailedEvent>(e =>
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackDependency("MongoDb", $"{e.CommandName} - {e.ToString()}", e.Failure.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Subtract(e.Duration), e.Duration, false);
    });
};
services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings));
```

Why do I have this issue and how is it possible to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I have a `count()` operation before my `insert()` and following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36#aggregation-pipeline) documentation it results in an aggregation request.